# php chmod returns true for success but doesn't actually change permissions

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

Perhaps I am not understanding how php's chmod() function should work, but I am experiencing it returning TRUE (indicating success) yet not actually modifying the permissions.

I am working with a file that has been uploaded to my web server's tmp directory.

```
    $fn = $value["tmp_name"];
    $fps = fileperms($fn);

    $testMsg .= "file permissions are $fps\n";        
    $testMsg .= "(which is " .  substr(sprintf('%o', $fps), -4) . ")\n";

    $arr = posix_getpwuid(fileowner($fn));
    $testMsg .= "file owner is " . $arr["name"] . "\n";

    $testMsg .= "running as: " . trim(shell_exec('whoami')) . "\n";


    //can i chmod it?
    $didChmod = chmod($fn, 0644);
    $testMsg .= "chmod: $didChmod\n";
    $fps = fileperms($fn);
    $testMsg .= "NEW file permissions are $fps\n";        
    $testMsg .= "(which is " .  substr(sprintf('%o', $fps), -4) . ")\n";
```

The output from the above is:

```
file permissions are 33152
(which is 0600)
file owner is www-data
running as: www-data
chmod: 1
NEW file permissions are 33152
(which is 0600)
```

As you can see, chmod() reported success yet did not change permissions.

Thanks

Comment: Is it on a filesystem that supports permissions? Sometimes have issues with network shares etc

Comment: @Anigel - yes, it's linux.

Comment: What are the permissions/owner on the directory? Also what happens if you shell_exec the chmod  instead of using the php built in?

Comment: @susiederkins What I think could be happening is that the server itself will not let you change the permissions because it belong "to the server" and not the owner itself. `tmp` files are automatically deleted once successfully `moved`. Try to test your chmod with the uploaded file itself, and you will see that it will work. *That's my theory.*

Comment: @Anigel The /tmp directory is owned by root and permissions are 777.  Interestingly, shell_exec makes the chmod work.  Why would that be?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will test your theory once my sys admin sets up a directory where I can actually move the tmp file.  right now I am just trying to use curl_exec to forward a request to another server and am trying to do so directly from /tmp.  curl_exec has been failing when trying to include the image, which is what made me suspect permissions in the first place and try to change them.

Comment: @susiederkins Keep me posted, I'm curious to know the results, cheers.

Comment: @susiederkins I thought it might, I have seen issues like this before where safe mode is enabled and the directory is not owned by the webserver even if the directory and files are 777.

Comment: @Fred-ii- for the record, your suggestion does indeed work.  chmod is successful when used after calling move_uploaded_file.

Comment: @susiederkins Hi Susie, kind of what I thought. Now, any news on the tmp file in question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- not quite sure what you mean by "any news?"  I can chmod it using shell_exec as Anigel suggested.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @susiederkins I was under that impression regarding what you said: *"I will test your theory once my sys admin sets up a directory..."*

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah - sorry if I was unclear. I confirmed that after I move a file from /tmp/randomfilename to a different directory (that which my sys admin set up for me), I am able to chmod it successfully (in its new location).  I was under the impression that that was your theory, and that's what I commented on an hour or so ago.  As for the original file in /tmp/randomfilename...well, the situation is of course unchanged.  chmod() does not work, but Anigel's suggestion of using shell_exec can work.

Comment: @susiederkins Not a problem. I'm still rather convinced that it's the server that "owns" the permissions for the tmp file and won't let you change it, unless you do it another way, like you said via `shell_exec`

Answer (score 0):

From the manual

> The current user is the user under which PHP runs. It is probably not
>   the same user you use for normal shell or FTP access. The mode can be
>   changed only by user who owns the file on most systems.

If this script is being run by the webserver (i.e. accessed via a browser), this PHP script will be run as the wrong user. Only the owner of the file (or root) can use chmod, the webserver is probably running as www-data or something, and therefore doesn't have permission to chmod.

Comment: Why would `trim(shell_exec('whoami'))` return as the owner of the file?  It appears the owner/executor of the script **is** the owner of the file.

Comment: My interpretation of the results is the same as @Kirk's - the php script is running as www-data, which is also the file owner.  So there should be permissions to chmod the file